# Spark becomes slow once I add a simple aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark, so maybe I am missing something.

I am playing around with structured streaming reading from json and outputing to console.

Here is the relevant part:

```
  def startFileJob(): Unit = {
    spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("myapp").getOrCreate()
    val inputDF = loadFromFile()
    val resultDF = aggregate(inputDF)
    writeToConsole(resultDF)
  }

  def loadFromFile(): DataFrame = {
    return spark.readStream.format("json")
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .option("header", true)
      .schema(jsonSchema)
      .option("path",  "input_data")
      .load()
  }

  def writeToConsole(dataFrame: DataFrame): Unit = {
    dataFrame
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("update")
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
  }

  def aggregate(inputDF:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
   inputDF
  }
```

The json file is plain simple, contains 4 rows with data like:

```
{ "date": "2021-05-08T10:01:01", "name": "some-stock", "bid": "23.4", "volume": "120" }
```

As you can see the above code basically does nothing just reads and writes the dataframe as it is.
When the App starts it reads the json immediately and prints to console.

But when I change the aggregate function to do some real -but simple- aggregation:

```
 def aggregate(inputDF:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
   inputDF.select("date","name", "bid", "volume")
  .groupBy(col("name"))
  .agg(max("bid").as("max_bid"))
  .withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp())
  }
```

Result: The app starts up and it struggles with it. It takes 53sec 100% of the time to print the result for this 4 line of json. Log doesn't show any error or warn.

Is this a bug or intentional behaviour by some extra settings for the aggregations?

Answer (score 0):

Had to set "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" to 1. Seems default value of 200 is disadvantageous for local run.